# Getting timezone name like abbreviation in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, timezone

I don't understand, all of it's sudden, below code started giving timezone abbreviation name instead of timezone actual name.

```
let timezone = TimeZone.current.identifier
```

**Result:** GMT

**Expecting:** Asia/Kolkata

[image: Playground output]

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: It works fine as you expects, for me. (Asia/Kolkata). Did you update/change anything/settings in your device?

Comment: It's because your **current timezone** is `GMT` and not `Asia/Kolkata`. If your current timezone would be `Asia/Kolkata` identifier would be `Asia/Kolkata`.

Comment: No, AFAIK Asia/Kolkata comes under GMT. But not those two are separate. Correct me If I'm wrong

Comment: `GMT` stands for `Greenwich Mean Time`, where `Greenwich` is location near `London, UK`. It's far away from `Kolkata`. And what I mean: check your timezone settings, they're invalid.

Answer (score 4):

**Note:** GMT does not represent timezone for Asia/Kolkata. (It should give you IST) You should check your device/simulator time zone settings. If you are testing simulator then check your (mac) system time zone.

Your snapshot indicates - you are trying with Playground editor. **Try to set location/time zone for your Mac system.**

> Mac System ► (Go to)  System Preference ► Date Time ► Time Zone (Here you can see your system time zone)

[image]

[image]

I tried following code with given results for IST/India:

```
print("**> TimeZone.current.identifier - \(TimeZone.current.identifier)\n")
// TimeZone.current.identifier - Asia/Kolkata

print("**> TimeZone.current.description - \(TimeZone.current.description)\n")
// TimeZone.current.description - Asia/Kolkata (current)

print("**> TimeZone.current.debugDescription - \(TimeZone.current.debugDescription)\n")
// TimeZone.current.debugDescription - Asia/Kolkata (current)
```